# Is this a totally bounded set in the space of continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

If $A=\{f\in C[0, 1]: \int^1_0|f(x)|^2\,dx\leq1\}$ and metric $d(f, g)$ is $(\int^1_0|f(x)-g(x)|^2dx)^\frac{1}{2}$. Is $A$ totally bounded? I know $A$ is clearly bounded since $d(f, 0)\leq 1$ under the chosen metric function. Any hint?

Comment: Suggestion: Find a subset of $A$ for which every two elements of $A$ are at least distance 1 apart.  Try functions of the form $a\sin(bx)$.

Comment: OK. Let's say $f_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x)$. Then $\int^1_0 |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2dx=\int^1_0 |2\cos(\frac{(m+n)\pi x}{2})\sin(\frac{(n-m)\pi x}{2})|^2dx$

Comment: $=4\int^1_0 \cos^2\frac{(m+n)\pi x}{2}\sin^2\frac{(n-m)\pi x}{2}dx$. Is this some special integration which leads to a constant, please?

Comment: It's easier if you write $|f_n-f_m|^2$ as $f_n^2 - 2 f_n f_m + f_m^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Solved in comments: not totally bounded, because the function $f_n(x) = \sin (\pi nx)$ satisfy $\int_0^1 f_n f_m =0$ for $n\ne m$, hence 
$$\int_0^1 |f_n-f_m|^2 = \int_0^1  f_n^2 +  f_m ^2 = 1 $$

---

**Remark**. Unless a   function space is finite-dimensional, its unit ball is not totally bounded with respect to its norm. (This is a general fact about normed spaces.) However, it frequently happens that unit ball with respect to one norm is totally bounded with respect to another, weaker norm. For example: the set 
$$\{f\in C[0,1] : \sup|f|\le 1\}$$
is compact in the metric $d$ defined in the post.