# Does there exist a sequence with $ \int_{[0,1]^2}| f_i - f_j |\, {\rm d}x = {\rm const.} > 0 $ for $ \forall i \neq j $?

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral, cauchy-sequences

Let $A = [0,1]^2$. Is there a such a sequence of functions $ f_i\colon A \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with $ \int_{A}| f_i | \ {\rm d}x  \leqslant 1$ and $ \int_{A} | f_i - f_j | \ {\rm d}x =  {\rm const.} > 0 $ for $ \forall i \neq j $ ? $ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 $

I have found this thread here: [Is this a totally bounded set in the space of continuous functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555228/is-this-a-totally-bounded-set-in-the-space-of-continuous-functions)
, which was very interesting, but not yet enough to give an example. At the moment I am still trying to figure out, whether such a sequence even exists. 
So I would be very happy for any constructive hint, comment, answer or recommendation for further reading. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $f_i$ really defined on the square $[0, 1]^2$?

Comment: Yes, the sequence is defined on  $ [0,1]^2 $, but at the moment I don't see, why it makes a big difference, if it were defined just on  $ [0,1] $ . I find a sequence that had that property to be rather weird.

Comment: I am just trying to understand your question. If $f_i$ is a function of two variables $x, y$ then $\int_{0}^{1} | f_i | \ dx$ is a function of $y$, so should that be bounded by $1$ for all $y$? And should   $\int_{0}^{1} | f_i - f_j | dx$ be constant as function of $y$ or constant as a function of $i$ and $j$?

Comment: You are right, problem is ill stated. I was hasty.

Comment: You did not mention them to be distinct, so any $f_i \equiv f$ will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu$ is an atomless measure then $L_1(\mu)$ contains an isometric copy of $\ell_2$ (actually of any $\ell_p$ for $p\in [1,2]$); for example take a sequence of independent Gaussian random variables, their span is isometric to $\ell_2$. Certainly, it is easy to find such a set in $\ell_2$ (any orthonormal basis would do). In conclusion, you can get $c=2^{1/p}$ for any $p\in [1,2]$.

Comment: I am afraid I can't follow. I know neither terms atomless measure, or independent Gaussian random variables. Is there a different way constructing an appropriate sequence relying just on the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Replace $\mu$ with the Lebesgue measure and it is fine. As for an explicit constriction, choose a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets $(A_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ that have positive measure. Let $f_k = \tfrac{1}{\mu(A_k)}\mathbf{1}_{A_k}$. Then $\int f_k = 1$. Can you compute $\int |f_k-f_m|$ for $n\neq m$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $1=a_1 > a_2 > \cdots \to 0.$ Let $S_n$ be the square $[a_{n+1},a_n]^2.$ Define $f_n = 1/(a_n-a_{n+1})^2$ on the interior of $S_n,$ $f=0$ elsewhere. Then $\int_A |f_n| = 1$ for all $n,$ and because the interiors of the $S_n$ are pairwise disjoint, we have

$$\int_A |f_n-f_m| = \int_A |f_n| +\int_A |f_m| = 2 \,\text { for all } m,n, m\ne n.$$

Comment: Yes, this is a particular version of the solution from the comment under my reply.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it. I saw your answer, and decided to write up a different answer.