# Equidistant sequence in a normed space

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed linear space of dimension $n < \infty$.

1. Is it always true that we can find a sequence of $m = n + 1$ points $x_i$ such that $\|x_i - x_j\| = c > 0$ for all $i\neq j$?
2. Can we choose $m$ to be bigger than $n+1$ without violating the first property?
3. In case $X$ is not finite-dimensional, does there always exist a countable sequence of $x_i$ with the desired property?

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548684/a-sequence-with-int-0-12-f-i-f-j-dx-const-for-forall-i-neq).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_dimension

Answer (score 0):

1. In the plane we can take the vertices of an equilateral triangle. In $n=3$ the vertices of a tetrahedron. In general, the vertices of a regular $n$-simplex. The construction is described in Wikipedia like this:

> Begin with a point A. Mark point B at a distance r from it, and join
>   to form a line segment. Mark point C in a second, orthogonal,
>   dimension at a distance r from both, and join to A and B to form an
>   equilateral triangle. Mark point D in a third, orthogonal, dimension a
>   distance r from all three, and join to form a regular tetrahedron. And
>   so on for higher dimensions.

2. It is easy to see that it is not possible in $n=1$ or $n=2$. This implies that it is not possible in higher dimensions. If it were possible in dimension $n$, delete a point and then it would be possible in dimension $n-1$.
3. The quoted construction can be carried out in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. For a general Banach space, I do not know.

### Edit

After reading Ilya's comment I realized that at least in some Banach space the answer to 2. and 3. is positive. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the norm of the maximum there are $2^n$ different points with mutual distance equal to $1$: $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ where $e_i=0$ or $1$. In $\ell^\infty$ this gives an uncountable set of points with mutual distance $1$. So the question is wether this is true on any Banach space.

Comment: Your first answer also need Hilbert structure it seems

Comment: Please see the edit to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for 3. the answer is no:

- P. Terenzi, Successioni regolari negli spazi di Banach, *Milan J.
  Math.*, **57** (1) (1987), 275–285.
- E. Glakousakis and S. K. Mercourakis, Examples of infinite
  dimensional Banach spaces without infinite equilateral sets,
  preprint, 2015, arXiv:1502.02500, to appear in *Serdica Math. J.*,
  **42** (2016).

see also Introduction in

> T. Kania, T. Kochanek, [Uncountable sets of unit vectors that are separated by more than 1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08166v4.pdf).

for the discussion of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, ${\rm conv}\ \{ x_1,\cdots, x_{n}\}$ has $n-1$ dimension so that we can find an extra point.
2. If $\| \ \|$ is strict, i.e., a unit sphere is strict convex surface or a shortest path between two points is unique, then we can not find $m$ point bigger than $n+1$. Assume that $\| \ \|$ is not strict. If $x_i,\ 1\leq i\leq n+2$ satisfies the property, then convex hull of $x_i, \ 1\leq i\leq n+1$ forms $n$-dimensional tetrahedron $T$. So shortest path $[x_{n+2}x_i] $ for some $i$ must penetrates $T$. So $\|\ \|_1,\ \|\ \|_\infty$ are possible. If unit sphere of $\|\ \|$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a hexagon, then it is not possible.