# Is equidistant points an open problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, open-problem

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1548755/1107685) post asks whether for any $n$-dimensional (presumably real) normed vector space, you can find $n+1$ equidistant points. They receive two answers saying that it is possible, but neither give much detail. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_dimension#Normed_vector_spaces) states that this is an open problem, though its source is from 1971. Neither of these seem particularly convincing as to whether the problem is open or not. They also seem to contradict each other.

So I would like to know whether it is an open problem whether for any $n$-dimensional normed vector space $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|)$ there is always a set of $n+1$ equidistant points.

Comment: I added some matrix stuff to my answer

Comment: @WillJagy Your answer covers inner product spaces, but not arbitrary normed spaces if the norm is not induced by an inner product.

Comment: i feel there should be a counter example, though other than the max norm, i can't think of any finite dimensional normed vector spaces that don't satisfy the parallelogram law off hand

Comment: @CSquared https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law this says any norm other than those generated by inner product spaces violates the parallelogram law. So anything other than elliptical norms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $n$  points at the unit directions, $(1,0,0...,0)$  and $(0,1,0,0..0)$ These are $\sqrt 2$ apart.

The final point, take as $(-t,-t,-t, ... , -t,-t)$   and find $t$  so the se diatnces are also $\sqrt 2$

Want $$  2 = (1+t)^2 + (n-1)t^2  $$
$$   2 =  n t^2 +2t + 1$$

$$ n t^2 +2t - 1 = 0$$

To get the same outcome  for a different inner product use matrices. By translating and shrinking my original example, I may put one of the points at the origin, all length one vectors and pairwise distances $1.$  That is, let my $n$ unit vectors make up the columns of a square matrix $P.$   The distance property says that $P^T P = W,$   where my $W$  will have all $1$   on the main diagonal and $1/2$  on all other elements.  If two unit vectors have dot product $\frac{1}{2}$  there is a $60^\circ$  angle between them, meaning distance $1$

You are now going to give me a positive symmetric matrix $G$   for which thenew inner product of $u,v$   will be $u^T G v.$  Now, we know that $G$ is a Gram matrix, meaning there is a matrix $R$   with $R^T R = G,$   while $R$  is also invertible.

Define $$   Q  = R^{-1} P  $$

Then  the (new)distances among the columns of $Q$
$$Q^T   GQ  = P^T R^{(-1)T}  R^T R  R^{-1}  P = P^T P = W $$

Your new $n+1$ points are the origin and the columns of $Q$

Next, here is the first page of a 2008 article settling many cases of the more general problem. But not all.

[image]

Comment: OP does not assume the Euclidean norm.

Comment: These are $\sqrt 2$ apart in the Euclidean norm, but in a different norm they might not be.

Comment: @ZoeAllen If you look at those vectors as coordinate vectors relative to an orthonormal basis, you get the same answer. But this does not cover normed spaces where the norm is not induced by an inner product.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are induced by an inner product are isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^n,\| \cdot \|_2)$ aren't they?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  true. I am not sure what the OP meant on that point.  So, how do we know that a symmetric convex body in the plane allows an equilaeral triangle?  Perhaps I see it, make a second copy of the convex body with center at  a boundary point of the original

Comment: @ZoeAllen Depends what you mean by "isomorphic". But in any case, the interesting case is for norms that are not induced by inner products.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603614  appeared in the Proceedings of the AMS.

Comment: I used that article to find this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.00066.pdf from 2017 saying the problem is still open.